# Is it possible to highlight interpolated perl variables in emacs?

Tags: perl, emacs, cperl-mode

Recently I've started using emacs and after overcoming a number of hurdles in making cperl-mode operate in a way that is agreeable I've become stumped by this problem. Currently I have all scalars in regular use being highlighted except for where they are interpolated. Is such syntax highlighting possible under this mode? Currently I'm using emacs 23.1 and jrockway's cperl-mode 5.23

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't highlight interpolated variables in strings, but it will do it in regular expressions.  I'll bet that could be adapted by somebody who knows elisp.